# Is there any method to communicate with a car ECU?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, automotive, smart-card

I want to build a device with AVR to read the car RPM from its ECU. I don't know how to receive data from ECU at all. The thing is important for me is Reading car RPM. any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

The car is

Peugeot 405

Comment: Does your car have an OBD port? It's probably worth mentioning make / model / year.

Comment: @PeterJ Unfortunately my knowledge about ECU is very less. How can I see if it has OBD port?

Comment: On my car the OBD port is tucked under the steering wheel, so you can get at it while in the driver's seat but you wouldn't spot it unless looking. I'm not sure if a Peugot 405 would have one or not, there are pictures here of what the connector looks like and other info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=obd+port&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=hADEUa3eGoyzhAe7l4CwCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQsAQ&biw=1262&bih=755 Have a look at these pictures ... they look like they can be almost anywhere...

Comment: Yes @PeterJ It has a port like this under the steering wheel. And exactly the thing I want is connecting an AVR board to this. to collect the data. but I don't know how?!

Comment: There's a chip called an ELM327 that does the hardware interface, I have a cable but have only ever used it with a laptop so not sure on the protocol details. But now you've confirmed it has an OBD port it's probably worth including in the question and hopefully someone else knows how to interface with an AVR and request the RPM data.

Answer (score 3):

[Elm Electronics](http://elmelectronics.com/obdic.html) makes a series of chips for interfacing a micro to the obdII port.

Doing this yourself or figuring out the protocol is a large project.

Alternately, you might consider tying into the crankcase sensor, or other sensor available on that particular car.  I assume this is diesel, so you can't tie into the fuel injection or ignition system?

Answer (score 0):

This uses the ELM327 mentioned by others; it is ready-to-go and includes the ODB2 cable.

[SparkFun OBD-II UART](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9555)

Answer (score 0):

After looking up how an electronic speedometer works your best bet is to go to the wheel sensor that sends pulses to the ECU in proportion to the speed you are going. Stopped no pulses with increased speed the pulses increase.
Then all you need is a circuit to transfer pulse frequency to a DC output Voltage that you manipulate to control your device.